# How to set Message from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have df like this

```
   a    b     c   
0  NaN  vc  
1  ds   NaN  Yg
2  er   re   re
```

i want df like this

```
   a    b     c     Status_a    Invalid_a   Status_b    Invalid_b   Status_c     Invalid_c
0  NaN  vc          Null/Blank   True        Valid         False   Null/Blank c    True
1  ds   NaN  Yg       valid a      False     Null/Blank b  True      Valid c       False
2  er   re   re       Valid a     False       Valid b      False     Valid c       False
```

condition is if Value is Nan or blank then Status_ is Null/Blank and Invalid_ True

i try with

```
def checkNull(ele,suffix):
    if pd.isna(ele) or (ele ==r'^\s+$'):
        return (f"Null OR Blank {suffix}",True)
    else :
        return ("Valid",False)
df[['Status_a','Invalid_a']] = df['a'].apply(checkNull, args=('a',)).tolist()
df[['Status_b','Invalid_b']] = df['b'].apply(checkNull, args=('b',)).tolist()
```

every time i call function but it is possible to this operation complete in once call the function

Answer (score 1):

If need call function for all columns use `for` with `f-strings`:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[[f'Status_{c}',f'Invalid_{c}']] = df[c].apply(checkNull, args=('a',)).tolist()

print (df)
     a    b    c         Status_a  Invalid_a         Status_b  Invalid_b  \
0  NaN   vc  NaN  Null OR Blank a       True            Valid      False   
1   ds  NaN   Yg            Valid      False  Null OR Blank a       True   
2   er   re   re            Valid      False            Valid      False   

          Status_c  Invalid_c  
0  Null OR Blank a       True  
1            Valid      False  
2            Valid      False
```

If need call function only for some columns use:

```
tested = ['a','b','c']
for c in tested:
    df[[f'Status_{c}',f'Invalid_{c}']] = df[c].apply(checkNull, args=('a',)).tolist()
```

Comment: it's Add message "<bound method IndexOpsMixin.tolist" of in Status_ column

Comment: @user14784453 - What is your python version?

Comment: my version python version is Python 3.7.4

Comment: @user14784453 - hmmm, there is no some typo? For me working well.

Comment: Okay no problem , i will try